# Scrolling Region on Left Side of Synaptics Touchpad?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, touchpad, scrolling

I have a laptop with a Synaptics touchpad that dual-boots Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10.  Is there any way in either of these operating systems to get a vertical scrolling region on the left side of my touchpad?  Having the scrolling region on the right side tends to be annoying for left-handed use, since it requires you to reach across the touchpad to scroll.  Ideally, I'd like to have scrolling regions on both sides of the touchpad, not just the left side, since I use the touchpad with both hands, not exclusively with my left hand.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem too, I use the following configuration to give me the opportunity to use left hand to trigger Circular Scrolling from top edge ...

http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130393/how-to-configure-the-touchpad-middle-click

```
##!/bin/sh
synclient LTCornerButton=3 LBCornerButton=2 RTCornerButton=3 RBCornerButton=2 TapButton3=2 ClickFinger2=0 ClickFinger3=0 LockedDrags=0 VertEdgeScroll=1 HorizEdgeScroll=1 VertTwoFingerScroll=1 HorizTwoFingerScroll=1 CircularScrolling=1 CircScrollTrigger=1 PalmDetect=1 CircularPad=0
```